# Odd threading behavior in python

Tags: python, multithreading, scope

I have a problem where I need to pass the index of an array to a function which I define inline. The function then gets passed as a parameter to another function which will eventually call it as a callback.

The thing is, when the code gets called, the value of the index is all wrong. I eventually solved this by creating an ugly workaround but I am interested in understanding what is happening here. I created a minimal example to demonstrate the problem:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import threading


def works_as_expected():
    for i in range(10):
        run_in_thread(lambda: print('the number is: {}'.format(i)))

def not_as_expected():
    for i in range(10):
        run_later_in_thread(lambda: print('the number is: {}'.format(i)))

def run_in_thread(f):
    threading.Thread(target=f).start()

threads_to_run_later = []
def run_later_in_thread(f):
    threads_to_run_later.append(threading.Thread(target=f))


print('this works as expected:\n')
works_as_expected()

print('\nthis does not work as expected:\n')
not_as_expected()
for t in threads_to_run_later: t.start()
```

Here is the output:

```
this works as expected:

the number is: 0
the number is: 1
the number is: 2
the number is: 3
the number is: 4
the number is: 6
the number is: 7
the number is: 7
the number is: 8
the number is: 9

this does not work as expected:

the number is: 9
the number is: 9
the number is: 9
the number is: 9
the number is: 9
the number is: 9
the number is: 9
the number is: 9
the number is: 9
the number is: 9
```

Can someone explain what is happening here? I assume it has to do with enclosing scope or something, but an answer with a reference that explains this dark (to me) corner of python scoping would be valuable to me.

I'm running this on python 2.7.11

Comment: I recommend firing up a debugger [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) will suffice, remove the working as expected part of code and just step through execution line by line, it will make it clear for you very fast about what is exactly going on

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul I think you are misunderstanding the point of my question. It's not that I don't understand what the code is doing. I don't understand why it is doing it. I am looking for an answer that helps me understand how the *language* actually works so I can be better at reasoning about code. Thanks for the suggestion though, I am quite fond of pdb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a result of how closures and scopes work in python.

What is happening is that `i` is bound within the scope of the `not_as_expected` function.  So even though you're feeding a `lambda` function to the thread, the variable it's using is being shared between each lambda and each thread.

Consider this example:

```
def make_function():
    i = 1
    def inside_function():
        print i
    i = 2
    return inside_function

f = make_function()
f()
```

What number do you think it will print?  The `i = 1` before the function was defined or the `i = 2` after?

It's going to print the *current* value of `i` (i.e. `2`).  It doesn't matter what the value of `i` was when the function was made, it's always going to use the *current* value.  The same thing is happening with your `lambda` functions.

Even in your *expected results* you can see it didn't always work right, it skipped `5` and displayed `7` twice.  What is happening in that case is that each lambda is *usually* running before the loop gets to the next iteration.  But in some cases (like the `5`) the loop manages to get through two iterations  before control is passed to one of the other threads, and `i` increments twice and a number is skipped.  In other cases (like the `7`) two threads manage to run while the loop is still in the same iteration and since `i` doesn't change between the two threads, the same value gets printed.

If you instead did this:

```
def function_maker(i):
    return lambda: print('the number is: {}'.format(i))

def not_as_expected():
    for i in range(10):
        run_later_in_thread(function_maker(i))
```

The `i` variable gets bound inside `function_maker` along with the `lambda` function.  Each lambda function will be referencing a different variable, and it will work as expected.

Comment: Fantastic. I didn't even notice that the *expected results* had the `5` and `7` anomaly.

Comment: It's very similar with Go's local variables in one `for` loop, you must pass the variable into a new function with a new scope, it will copy the variable value.

Comment: But when I works with multiple threads, variables in outer scope of a closure are missing and raised `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'values' referenced before assignment`.

Answer (score 2):

A closure in Python captures the free **variables**, not their current values at the time of the creation of the closure. For example:

```
def capture_test():
    i = 1
    def foo():
        return i
    def bar():
        return i
    print(foo(), bar()) # 1 1
    i = 2
    print(foo(), bar()) # 2 2
```

In Python you can also capture variables and write to them:

```
def incdec():
    counter = 0
    def inc(x):
        nonlocal counter
        counter += x
        return counter
    def dec(x):
        nonlocal counter
        counter -= x
        return counter
    return inc, dec

i1, d1 = incdec()
i2, d2 = incdec()
print(i1(10), i1(20), d1(3))   # 10 30 27
print(i2(100), d2(5), d2(20))  # 100 95 75
print(i1(7), d2(9))            # 34 66
```

As you see `incdec` returns a pair of two closures that captured the same variable and that are incrementing/decrementing it. The variable shared by `i1`/`d1` is however different from the variable shared by `i2`/`d2`.

One common mistake is for example to expect that

```
L = []
for i in range(10):
    L.append(lambda : i)
for x in L:
    print(x())
```

will display the numbers from 0 to 9... all of the unnamed closures here captured the same variable `i` used to loop and all of them will return the same value when called.

The common Python idiom to solve this problem is

```
L.append(lambda i=i: i)
```

i.e. using the fact that default values for parameters are evaluated at the time the function is created. With this approach each closure will return a different value because they're returning their private local variable (a parameter that has a default).